# import VDB file and start the animation at a certain frame in your scene

Tags: animation, volumetrics

Hi I have created a VDB file explosion and it looks great.  I Have imported it into another project and it all works.

This is using Blender 3.6

However I would like to change the frame that it appears on.

Is it possible to have it start on frame 30 or frame 50 in this project?  Or do I have to go back to the original VDB animation and reconfigure it?

I see the offset option but I believe that this is to use only part of the VDB file itself.  I want the whole vdb file just would like it to start at a different frame in this new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple, in the settings for the *OpenVDB File* there is a *Start* value. This is the one on which you want the simulation to start.

If you hover your mouse over it, the appearing tooltip says: "Global starting frame of the sequence, assuming first has a #1". That sounds a bit mysterious maybe, it means if your sequence starts with 1, this starting point will be placed on the frame you specify with the *Start* value (if *Offset* is 0).

The *Frames* are to say how long the sequence is (if you set a lower value then the sequence contains, they will be cut at the end) and the *Offset* as you already suspected is how many frames you want to be cut off at the beginning of the sequence.

[image: starting frame]

Comment: Thanks I noticed that and the summary left me thinking it related to the VDB file itself, it did make me confused.